# How to integrate Hybris Custom and Config folder to local installation?

Tags: bitbucket, sap-commerce-cloud

I installed Hybris 1905 out of the box locally on my machine and I would like to include the custom code which our project stores on bitbucket.

To track the progress of the commits, I installed earlier Sourcetree and have integrated the repository. The repo is stored locally in directory

```
C:\git\projectname
```

How can I now get the folders custom and config into my local installation to be able to run always the latest code in my local machine? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a symlink or directory junction.

Assuming your custom config is stored in `C:\git\projectname\config` and your custom code is stored in `C:\git\projectname\bin\custom`

In **`hybrisHomeDirectory`**, open command prompt then type :

```
mklink /J config C:\git\projectname\config
```

this will create a directory junction that link your config to hybris installation folder.

In **`hybrisHomeDirectory/bin`**, open command prompt then type :

```
mklink /J custom C:\git\projectname\bin\custom
```

This will create a directory junction that link your custom code.

If you want to create a symlink instead of directory junction (requires admin), then open cmd as administrator and type `mklink /D` instead of `mlink /J`

Answer (score 0):

1. Config folder

In order to refer a config folder(other than the default one) you can edit your h*ybris\bin\platform\setantenv.bat*. For example please have a look at my setantenv.bat that I used in the past:

```
@echo off
set ANT_OPTS=-Xmx2g -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djdk.util.jar.enableMultiRelease=force
set ANT_HOME=%~dp0apache-ant
set PATH=%ANT_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
rem deleting CLASSPATH as a workaround for PLA-8702
set CLASSPATH=

Rem Custom zone start
set HYBRIS_RUNTIME_PROPERTIES=%~dp0local_custom.properties
chcp 65001
set HYBRIS_CONFIG_DIR=%~dp0..\..\..\gitrepo\config

echo -------CustomChanges--------
echo CustomChanges: configFolder: %HYBRIS_CONFIG_DIR%
echo CustomChanges: runTimeProperties: %HYBRIS_RUNTIME_PROPERTIES%
echo -------CustomChanges--------
Rem Custom zone end

echo ant home: %ANT_HOME%
echo ant opts: %ANT_OPTS%
ant -version
```

Between **Rem Custom zone start** and **Rem Custom zone end** there is the Custom section that, among other things, sets the path to the config folder.

In my case, hybris folder and gitrepo folder are right next to eachother(in the same parent folder) and that is why the following path(also mentioned above) works:

```
set HYBRIS_CONFIG_DIR=%~dp0..\..\..\gitrepo\config
```

Keeping these two folders next to each other makes it easier to use relatives paths in order to easily use resources from git Repo into Hybris.

2. Custom folder

In order for Hybris to take into consideration the custom extensions, their folder needs to be specified in the **localextensions.xml** as exemplified below:

```
<path autoload="true" dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/../../gitRepo/extensions"/>
```

Again, above relative path works for me because hybris and gitrepo folders are next to each other.

Comment: I checked your proposal, but I'm struggeling a little with the paths, for 1. Config and 2. Custom. 

My local hybris installation is in C:\KBData\hybris-kbecom and my needed custom git files are in C:\KBData\git\kbecom

Now my question, how should the path for 1. Config and 2. Custom be? I tried the following:

1. Config:

%~dp0..\..\..\git\kbecom\config


2. Custom:

<path autoload="true" dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/../../git/kbecom/bin/custom/kbecom"/>

Further do I have to build hybris again afterwards first, or can sync eclipse directly?

Thank you!

Comment: Where is your setantenv.bat ? Assuming it is here: C:\KBData\hybris-kbecom\hybris\bin\platform\setantenv.bat then the path you should use is the following 1. Config: %~dp0..\..\..\..\git\kbecom\config 2. Custom: <path autoload="true" dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/../../../git/kbecom/bin/custom/kbecom"/>. You can also try absolute paths(Config: C:\KBData\git\kbecom\config) in the beginning to check how it works. You need to build hybris and make sure that the intended folders are taken into consideration.

Comment: I do not know how eclipse handles this form of setup. I use intellij with "Integration for Sap Commerce" plugin which helps setting the custom and config folder as I want

Comment: I will have a look - thank you for your Support!